# Windows command prompt hangs for indefinite time

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd

I have a script that performs upgrade to a database.

The script also logs before the upgrade starts, but when this script tries to access the log file it hangs for an indefinte time.

The line that's causing the issue is:

```
 %LOGMESSAGE%  Start update %UPDVERSION% .
```

LOGMESSAGE is a cmd file which is as follow:

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET /A FT=500
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year
/Format:table') DO (
 IF NOT !FT!==500 GOTO proceed
 SET  FD=%%F-%%D-%%A
 SET  FT=%%B:%%C:%%E
:proceed
 SET /A FX="DS"
)    
endlocal
```

The main function of the LOGMESSAGE is to get the current system time.

The log file into which the scripts writes to has no issues and so does the function LOGMESSAGE, as the log file is written many times before the line  `%LOGMESSAGE%  Start update %UPDVERSION% .` is called. The script seems to work without any hassle on many other computer, but I am having an issue with one server, the server is running windows server 2003 R2 SP2.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /A FT=500
FOR /F "tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table^|find "20"') DO (
    IF NOT !FT!==500 GOTO proceed
    SET  FD=%%F-%%D-%%A
    SET  FT=%%B:%%C:%%E
    :proceed
    SET /A FX="DS"
)    
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks a ton but that didnt seem to work, I tried adding echos in the script, and figured it out that it hangs on the for statement and never leaves it. It exactly hangs on `FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year
/Format:table')`. Any idea why is it hanging? the system has AMD processor. Could that be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the date and time, you can use

```
DATE /T
TIME /T
```

instead of WMI.

Comment: yes, but wmic will give the same format on all systems independent of local settings.

Answer (score 0):

Three comments:

`.cmd` files are rare - normally, `.bat` files are used. There *are* minor differences between the two, but I'm not sure whether they would be relevant (I can no longer remember them...)

It's perfectly legitimate to have have a line-break just before the opening single-quote and just after the closing. A break in the middle of the command, I'm not sure about - not saying this **IS** a problem, but it's so easily eliminated.

I'm no longer sure, since I rarely use XP any more, and never S2003 - but ISTR there were problems with having a label within a block statement. The label seemed to end the block.

So - I'd suggest

running the routine as a `.bat` instead of a `.cmd`, using

```
for...(
 'whatever whatever...'
 ) do (
```

structure, and implementing whatever tomfoolery is happening about `FD`, `FT` and `FX` within a subroutine.